# JFX Webview post JAVA 1.8.0_121 getting worse

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, webkit

I was excited about the Java updates coming after 121. But each subsequent release, has made the Java FX Web View progressively worse and has made it increasingly difficult to maintain basic functionalities of web kit that were actually in line with the latest releases of webkit.

One example, when debugging with firebug lite, in version 144 clicking on any object to expand the object causes the entire application to crash immediately.

CSS animations based on height properties no longer function, which is a step back given that they function in the latest versions of webkit.

Flex Box also no longer functions properly.

I believe bugs are being introduced and **I would like to know where the best place to report them** with specific examples would be, and how likely it is that oracle will actually try to fix them.

Also it has been hard to find an easy way to track all the **changes** that are being made with each update. What is the easiest way to **track** this?

Alternatively it could be the case that the mentioned features are actually being phased out by the latest versions of webkit but have not been introduced yet, and JFX is simply thinking ahead. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having checked whether your bug has already been reported, you can create a new bug report here: http://bugreport.java.com/
Give as much information as you can and provide an executable test case for it. Normally it just takes one to two days until your bug has been examined and will be entered here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa
There you can watch the progress of your bug.